# Windows Authentication In Angular 6 Application and ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular6

Please help,
I am not able to get User.Identity.Name, it is coming empty  however i add system.security.principle and System.diagonstics.application also.

Comment: Are you using claims?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue when using ASP.Net Core2, I have stored logged in users mail id in the claim and obtain it later from identity.

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var userMailId = identity?.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub)?.Value;
```

You can store name in CLaim and retrieve it later.